# How can I identify patterns over several rows in a column and fill a new column with information about that pattern using R?

Tags: r, repeat

I am working with a dataset where I have a dummy variable that tells me when a participant is near a chair and when the participant is away from the chair. I have an id for each participant and the dummy = 1 when the participant is near the chair and 0 when they are a certain feet away. The data updates every 30 seconds or so (it isn't perfectly timed, so I can't use that information to help identify the pattern). If a participant stops at the chair for 2 minutes then we would have 4 observations where `D=1`. Using the dummy variables I want to identify the start of the participant moving away from the chair and then moving back towards it. I would also like to filly a column with variable (or something like `TRUE` when it fits that pattern or leaving, wandering, and coming back).

note: The overall event could end with the individual away from the chair or near.

`df1` illustrates and example of the dataframe I'm working with and `df2` is the final dataframe. I assume I have to use regex or grep to get the final output, but I'm not particularly familiar with either and I could use some guidance!

```
df1

TIME        ID        D
12:30:10    2         0
12:30:42    2         0
12:30:59    2         1
12:31:20    2         0
12:31:50    2         0
12:32:11    2         0
12:32:45    2         1
12:33:10    2         1
12:33:33    2         1
12:33:55    2         1
12:34:15    2         0
12:34:30    2         0
```

What I'd like to have in the end:

```
df2

TIME        ID        D      Pattern
12:30:10    2         0      FALSE
12:30:42    2         0      FALSE
12:30:59    2         1      TRUE
12:31:20    2         0      TRUE     
12:31:50    2         0      TRUE
12:32:11    2         0      TRUE
12:32:45    2         1      TRUE
12:33:10    2         1      FALSE
12:33:33    2         1      FALSE
12:33:55    2         1      FALSE
12:34:15    2         0      FALSE
12:34:30    2         0      FALSE
```

Eventually I want to end up with a data frame where the observations only include the rows that are TRUE.

Once again, the dataframe includes several IDs and events like this.

Thanks!

Comment: How do row 3-7 become `TRUE`? What logic do you apply here?

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table` approach of things...

*sample data*

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("TIME        ID        D
12:30:10    2         0
12:30:42    2         0
12:30:59    2         1
12:31:20    2         0
12:31:50    2         0
12:32:11    2         0
12:32:45    2         1
12:33:10    2         1
12:33:33    2         1
12:33:55    2         1
12:34:15    2         0
12:34:30    2         0")
#you can also use data.table::setDT( mydata ) to make mydata
#  a data.table. If so, make sure to replace DT below with mydata.
```

*code*

```
#create a list with strings of all D's by ID
temp <- DT[, .( D = paste0( D, collapse = "" ) ), by = .(ID) ]
#build a named replace vector, base on the 1[0]+1-pattern
replace_vector <- gsub( ".", "A", unlist( stringr::str_extract_all( temp$D, "1[0]+1" ) ) )
names( replace_vector ) <- unlist( stringr::str_extract_all( temp$D, "1[0]+1" ) )
#and replace the parts we want to keep with A's
temp[, D2 := stringr::str_replace_all( D, replace_vector )]
#paste pack to original DT
DT[, keep := temp[, strsplit( D2, ""), by = .(ID) ]$V1 ]
#now filter what you want to keep, and drop the keep column
DT[keep == "A", ][, keep := NULL][]
```

*output*

```
#        TIME ID D
# 1: 12:30:59  2 1
# 2: 12:31:20  2 0
# 3: 12:31:50  2 0
# 4: 12:32:11  2 0
# 5: 12:32:45  2 1
```